# how i update multiple table using viewmodel in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, viewmodel, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

**Employee Model**

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Departments { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    }
```

**Department Model**

```
public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }
```

**View Model for Department and Employee**

```
public class EDViewModel
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Department Departments { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now i want to update both tables with single view.

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int?id)
        {
// write some code for update both table at once time
}
```

**PostMethod**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EDViewModel Emodel)
        {
            var user = db.Employees.Where(c => c.Employee_Id == Emodel.Employee_Id).FirstOrDefault();
            user.UserName = Emodel.UserName;
            user.ProfilePicture = Emodel.ProfilePicture;
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
```

> But in this method only Update Employee record not department

Comment: have alook at this might help you.http://technotipstutorial.blogspot.com/2016/12/part-20-add-edit-record-using-partial.html

Comment: can you show us a bit of what you tried already that is failing?

Comment: Thank for comment 
please check code again i update it :)

Answer (score 0):

After many searching finally i get a solid solution 
hope you like or improve this.

**Controller**

```
 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            MYDb db = new MYDb();
            var user = db.Employees.Where(c => c.Employee_Id == Emodel.Employee_Id).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                var vm = new EDViewModel { Employee_id = user.Employee_id, departmentName = user.departmentName };
                if (user.department != null)
                {
                    user.Departmet_id = vm.Departments.Departmet_id;
                    user.DepartmentName = vm.Departments.DepartmentName;
                    user.Employee_id = vm.employee_id;
                    user.employeeName = vm.employeeName;
                }
                return View(user);
            }
            return Content("Invalid Id");
        }

 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(EDViewModel Emodel)
        {
            var user = db.Employees.Where(c => c.Employee_Id == Emodel.Employee_Id).FirstOrDefault();
            user.EmployeeId = Emodel.EmployeeId;
            user.EmployeeName= Emodel.EmployeeName;
          user.DepartmentName= Emodel.Departmt.DepartmentName;
         // Just remove this line
          //  db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Home");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me 
just remove this

```
 db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

if we not remove this **entityvalidation** occur